# Creando un array multidimensional con php y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy creando una array multidimensional, que por necesidad debe ser algo como esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Las longitudes (225,250...950) no siempre serán las mismas, depende de lo que haya en la base de datos, al igual que las categorías(T1,T2,T3...T12)

Hice un procedimiento almacenado para crear esta tabla en la base de datos:

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
                CONCAT(
                    'ROUND (SUM( IF(longitud_inv = '
                    , longitud_inv
                    , ', volumen,0) ),2) AS `'
                    , longitud_inv , '`'
                )
                order by longitud_inv ASC
            )
        FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
    );  
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT("T",id_cat),"TOTAL") AS "Categoria/Long", ', 
                  @sql_dynamic, ',

               ROUND (SUM(volumen),2) AS Total
               FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
               INNER JOIN Categoria_RW_OP ON inventario_ingreso_detalle.categoria_inv = Categoria_RW_OP.idCategoria_RW
               GROUP BY 
               id_cat WITH ROLLUP'
           );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Sin embargo, tengo 2 problemas: Al llamar el procedimiento, como no tiene un valor de retorno claro, no muestra nada en pantalla y no sé de qué otra forma llamarlo.
Segundo: Trato de hacer la consulta desde php, sin un stored procedure, pero igual no me está mostrando nada.

Este es el código PHP que utilizo:

```
    $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( distinct
        CONCAT(
            'ROUND(SUM(IF(longitud_inv = '
            , longitud_inv
            , ', volumen,0) 
            ),2) AS '`'
            , longitud_inv . '`'
        )
        order by longitud_inv ASC
    )
    FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
    CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT('T', id_cat), 'TOTAL') AS 'Categoria/Long',', '
    ROUND(SUM(volumen),2) AS Total
    FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
    INNER JOIN Categoria_RW_OP ON inventario_ingreso_detalle.categoria_inve = Categoria_RW_OP.idCategoria_RW
    GROUP BY 
    id_cat WITH ROLLUP'
    )
    ";

$result= mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'] , $sql);
if ($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $row['volumen'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. No necesitas un procedimeinto almacenado para eso, puedes pasar la consulta (`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( ....`  directamente a la BD desde PHP. Si no te muestra nada es porque debe haber algún error. Primero decide cómo lo quieres hacer y en base a eso se te podrá ayudar mejor.

Comment: El procedimiento almacenado ya me muestra la tabla que puse en un inicio en el workbench, el problema es que, cuando llamo el procedimiento en PHP y lo monto en un HTML, no me muestra nada.

Comment: Bueno, pero eso puede deberse a muchas cosas: que la conexión a la base de datos no se realiza desde PHP, que manejas mal los datos, que llamas mal al procedimiento almacenado, que construyes mal la tabla, etc. ¿Hiciste alguna prueba tipo `var_dump` con los datos que recibes?  ¿Qué código PHP estás usando?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( distinct
  CONCAT(
   'ROUND(SUM(IF(longitud_inv = '
   , longitud_inv
   , ', volumen,0) 
   ),2) AS '`'
   , longitud_inv . '`'
  )
  order by longitud_inv ASC
 )
 FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
 CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT('T', id_cat), 'TOTAL') AS 'Categoria/Long',', '
 ROUND(SUM(volumen),2) AS Total
 FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
 INNER JOIN Categoria_RW_OP ON inventario_ingreso_detalle.categoria_inve = Categoria_RW_OP.idCategoria_RW
 GROUP BY 
 id_cat WITH ROLLUP'
 )
 ";

Comment: $result= mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'] , $sql);
if ($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
 echo $row['volumen'];
    }
  }
}
El resto del código
como no me estaba funcionando el procedimiento almacenado por los valores de retorno, ingresé lo mejor que pude la misma consulta en PHP

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/219014/edit) agregando en ella el código completo. En comentarios es imposible analizarlo. ... Una cosa difícil de entender es por ejemplo por qué usas tu conexión dentro de `$GLOBALS`  ¿?  Gracias.

Comment: Es una necesidad de la empresa en la que estoy desarrollando el sistema, disculpa no poder dar más datos al respecto.

Comment: Tú estás haciendo `echo $row['volumen'];`, pero en el ejemplo que muestras no hay ninguna columna llamada así. Puedes poner un `print_r($row);` temporalmente para verificar si está trayendo datos.

Comment: Si te soy sincero, mi principal problema (en PHP ) es que no sé como realizar la misma consulta del procedimiento almacenado y guardarlo correctamente para poder llamarlo con un echo... no sé si me expliqué bien.

Comment: La consulta no es otra cosa que una cadena que contiene una instrucción SQL válida. La diferencia en PHP es que debes construir tu consulta tal cual como una cadena. O sea, en PHP sería cuestión de escribir tu consulta concatenando las dos cadenas que defines en el manejador con `SET @sql_dynamic ` y con `SET @sql = CONCAT ... `

Comment: Tal y como te dice @A.Cedano el problema que tienes es que tu consulta SQL no tiene declarado ningún campo llamado `volumen`, por lo que `$row['volumen']` no estará definido. Es probable que quieras asignar dicho nombre al resultado del `GROUP_CONCAT()` poniendo `) volumen` antes del primer `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, he escrito este código para ayudarte a encontrar el problema.

Está totalmente controlado y te dirá exactamente lo que está ocurriendo.

A mi me parece extraño que la conexión exista dentro de GLOBALS.

Además, no tienes ninguna columna llamada `volumen`. Yo usé otro *fetch_style` para imprimir la primera columna, sea cual sea, sólo como prueba.

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( distinct
        CONCAT(
            'ROUND(SUM(IF(longitud_inv = '
            , longitud_inv
            , ', volumen,0) 
            ),2) AS '`'
            , longitud_inv . '`'
        )
        order by longitud_inv ASC
    )
    FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
    CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT('T', id_cat), 'TOTAL') AS 'Categoria/Long',', '
    ROUND(SUM(volumen),2) AS Total
    FROM inventario_ingreso_detalle
    INNER JOIN Categoria_RW_OP ON inventario_ingreso_detalle.categoria_inve = Categoria_RW_OP.idCategoria_RW
    GROUP BY 
    id_cat WITH ROLLUP'
    )
    ";

$mysqli=$GLOBALS['link'];   
if($mysqli){
    if ( $result= mysqli_query($mysqli , $sql) ){
        if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
                echo $row[0];
            }
        } else {
            echo "Cero registros encontrados";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
} else {
    echo "No hay conexion... Lo de GLOBALS es muy raro";
}
```

Es un *código que habla*, está obligado a decirte lo que pasa. Espero te sirva y si hay que refinarlo lo haremos.